# Collection store exception adding all List<Opportunity> to List<Account>

Tags: apex, list, sobject

I a have a problem in my code, i try to merge two lists into a Sobject list in order to optimize the DML operation, but i get this error during run time:

```
Collection store exception adding all List<Opportunity> to List<Account>
```

here is my code:

```
List<sObject> listSobjects = (List<Sobject>) listAccounts;
List<sObject> listSobjectOpportunity = (List<sObject>) opportunityList;
listSobjects.addAll(listSobjectOpportunity);
Database.SaveResult[] tt = Database.update(listSobjects, false);
```

Any ideas how to make it work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instantiate a new generic list and it won't carry over any type information. Simply casting to `List<SObject>` doesn't remove the fact it was originally a `List<Account>`.

```
List<SObject> records = new List<SObject>();
records.addAll(accounts);
records.addAll(opportunities);
```